# TextView wrapping not working properly inside a GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout in a lightweight app (please, don't suggest adding new dependencies, like `Appcompat` or `ConstraintLayout`, they all add more than 1MB to the APK):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:columnCount="2">

  <TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="Left text. word1 word2 word3" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="Right text. word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10" />
</GridLayout>
```

Unfortunately, the result is incorrect: the second `TextView` is trying to grow too big, resulting in the text being truncated:
[image: screenshot]

It looks like the `TextView` is expanding until it reaches the width of its parent, and only then starts wrapping. But it should only grow until it reaches the width it was allocated by its parent. Is it an obvious bug in `TextView`, or did I misuse it? Any idea how I could fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using `FrameLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
            />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/short_string"
            />

    </FrameLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've not set layout_height and layout_width for the TextViews, which I believe is the issue. Set height as wrap_content and width as match_parent.

Comment: Setting layout_width of the TextView is definitely making things worse: it forces them to have the same width as the whole parent, which is wrong even when the text content is much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

you can use linearlayout instead like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Left text. word1 word2 word3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="Right text. word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried to simplify my example as much as I could. It contains only 3 views/viewgroup instead of 20, and the GridLayout may look superfluous, but it's really used, so I need a solution that keeps it.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using wrap content for the TextView. instead of a definite width